# Functionality unique to Win32 API?

Tags: winapi

It seems that the Win32 API (*the* C API for native Windows applications) is becoming more and more overtaken by more modern frameworks and toolkits, including Microsoft's own WPF and Qt.

If the programming language is not a concern -- if you're not set on a managed environment, or a functional programming style, etc. -- does Win32 API bring anything to the table?  **Is there any functionality that one can implement with Win32 API that's not available with WPF or other frameworks?**

I know it's possible to mix Win32 code into WPF/managed software, so one doesn't have to choose one or the other.  But what are some examples of needing to break out Win32 API when developing a program in a higher-level language/framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly.

All the frameworks are written in terms of the Win32 API.  The frameworks cover 80-95% of what programmers need to do, but if you need really low-level control over something, you'll need to drop to the underlying Win32 API.  Some examples would be:

1. precise control over text rendering (via [DirectWrite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368038%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)),
2. detailed control over speech recognition using [SAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723627%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (there are literally dozens of interfaces not exposed through System.Speech),
3. low-level networking code (i.e., anything not HTTP related),
4. Practically *anything* [audio related](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/desktop/dd370802%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), if you're interested in performance.

Comment: Neat broad description +1

Comment: The frameworks cover 5% of what you need to do, except if it is a really simple appication.

Answer (score 3):

Another more specific example is "windows hooks".

I needed to hook some socket programs at some point and the only possible way was windows api.

To elaborate i wanted to receive all communication received on some listening socket on a different one. Doing this requires [hooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

... and don't forget about direct hardware access like "WinUSB" and debugging functionality (writing programs that act as debuggers).

Answer (score 0):

The Win32 API is nowhere close to be taken over by any framework at the moment. 
If that was the case, most of the API would not be updated by Microsoft. Instead, lots of new interfaces are added and updated.

There are framekorks like Qt, but, unless what you need to create is trivial, you will eventually use the API, especially for new graphics libraries, audio, video, usb, ribbon, sockets, network, COM automation, biometrics, encryption, digital signatures, security, scripting, etc.

Actually, most libraries are quite outdated and, while you *can* create an application that relies mostly on worker threads and not on the interface, building a nice, modern and useful application today certainly requires the API. So investing on a framework that would only cover a minimum part of your application is not worth the learning curve, these frameworks mostly target really new and unexperienced windows developers.